# How to view Export Mailbox status in Mail App?

Tags: macos, mail.app

How to view Export Mailbox status in Mail App?

I am trying to archive my mails: I created a Smart Mailbox, which includes the mails received in last year, then right click Export Mailbox to a `.mbox` file.

In the User Interface of Mail App, no export progress/ status is being displayed. How can I view the export status?

I can now only guess the export status is complete or not by checking the `.mbox` filename contains `.partial` or not.

Comment: do you have a mail box with >20 Gig size?

Comment: The smart mailbox is around 10GB size so far. Backup took around 2 hours.

Answer (score 3):

So I spent the last 3 days trying to export 500GB worth of Apple / Mac Mail and could not find a good answer anywhere. So I came up with a system that worked for me.

1. Begin export by right-clicking a mailbox in Mac Mail, and click **Export**. Don't forget the **Options** button on that screen as it allows you to include subfolders, and it's not included by default.
2. Go to the folder where you chose to export mail. Set your **View To List**, and sort by **Date Modified**.
3. If a mailbox is still getting migrated, it will have the word **Partial** in its filename. Once done, it will automatically remove that word so you know that box is done. If you have subfolders in your mailboxes, it will first create a folder with your mailbox name and `subfoldername.partial.mbox` will appear in your export folder. Once all subfolders are exported, You will also see a `mbox` file for the parent mailbox. That is all. Enjoy!

Comment: that's what I have mentioned in the question, checking the `.partial` extension

Answer (score 1):

Window > Activity - will show you what the mail app is busy with

i.e. Exporting mailbox, copying 2551 of 3762 messages and a progress bar

Comment: **Not** working for me (macOS 10.12.6) -- the Activity window is empty

Comment: Yes **export will not appear in there** at all. There is no way to know the status of the export. That, IMO, is pretty creepy.

Comment: You can "Get Info" from the `.mbox` folder. If the file size does not change for a period of time, it means that the export progress is complete. Not a very good user experience, though.